Maximum call stack size exceeded with Anime.js
I want to create a preloader animation for each page. Using the anime.js library. But now I have an error in the console - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. How can I solve it?


class PageTransition extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    anime({
      targets: this,
      translateX: ["0%", "-100%"],
      easing: "easeInOutQuad",
      duration: 1000,
      delay: 500,
    });
  }
}

customElements.define("page-transition", PageTransition);

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
  <body class="gradient">
    <page-transition class="loading-bar"></page-transition>
    </main>
  </body>



